# Firebase how to index this data to be fetched?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a DB with `users` and `items`.

Every user has `languages`, which is an array of languages, for example `['en', 'ar']`

Every item has `language`, which is a string, for example `'en'`.

How can I index my items, such that I can get a list of the last X items in an array of languages? (i.e - latest 5 items who are either 'en' or 'ar')

For a single language the solution is simple - have an index that has the language key, and array of item keys ordered by whatever.

Comment: I think this is a little confusing without some images or your database structure bt now and the platform you'll use it (android, ios, web). So every user can have multiple languages, but items is just one language? is there something else on items?

Comment: Yep. Every user has multiple languages, and item has a single language. item also has a `title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the Firebase official documentation recommends against using `arrays`. IMHO, the main problem in your project is that you trying to use an array, which is an anti-pattern when it comes to `Firebase`. Beside that, one of the many reasons Firebase recommends against using arrays is that it makes the security rules impossible to write. Because a Firebase database is structured as pairs of key and values, the best option is to use a `Map`.

To achieve what you want, i recomand you using a database structure which looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- users
    |     |
    |     --- UID1
    |     |    |
    |     |    --- languages
    |     |            |
    |     |            --- languageId1: true
    |     |            |
    |     |            --- languageId2: true
    |     |
    |     --- UID2
    |          |
    |          --- languages
    |                  |
    |                  --- languageId3: true
    |                  |
    |                  --- languageId4: true
    |
    --- languages
    |      |
    |      --- languageId1
    |      |      |
    |      |      --- languageName: "en"
    |      |      |
    |      |      --- items
    |      |           |
    |      |           --- itemId1: true
    |      |
    |      --- languageId2: "ar"
    |      |      |
    |      |      --- languageName: "ar"
    |      |      |
    |      |      --- items
    |      |           |
    |      |           --- itemId2: true
    |
    --- item
         |
         --- itemId1
         |     |
         |     --- title: "ItemTitleEn"
         |     |
         |     --- en: true
         |
         --- itemId2
               |
               --- title: "ItemTitleAr"
               |
               --- ar: true
```

Now, with this database structure you can achieve everything you want. For example, you can query your database to display all languages from you database. You can also display all the languages of a single user.

If you want to query your database for the last x item which have the language set to `en`, you just need to put a listener on the `items` node and create a query using functions like: `orderByChild()`, `equalsTo()` and `limitToLast()`. Such a query should look like this:

```
query = rootRef.child("items")
    .orderByChild("en")
    .equalsTo(true)
    .limitToLast(5)
    .addListener(/* ... */)
```

**EDIT:** Unfortunately Firebase does not allow multiple conditions in a query. So in Firebase there is no where clause that sounds like this: `WHERE language = "en" AND language = "ar"`. So to solve this, you need to put a listener on the other node, on `languages` node.

The flow is as follows:

```
yourRef = rootRef.child("languages"); //only one listener
yourRef.addListener(
    1. Create a list
    2. get items from dataSnapshot.child("languageId1").child("items").getChildren()
    3. add **en** items to the list
    4. get items from dataSnapshot.child("languageId2").child("items").getChildren()
    5. add **ar** items to the list
    6. display the list that contains data from both languages
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good to know that firebase recommends objects and not arrays, but this doesn't answer my question, on how to build the data such that I will be able to get in a single list items from 2 languages

Comment: However truly an answer that will work, it is not practical imo. It seems I must do something with elastic. (can't award bounty for next 19 hours)

Comment: Ok. Cheers Amit!